# Handling multiple volatile tables from Teradata in Python

Tags: python, teradata

I'm trying to understand how can I use more than one volatile table (from Teradata) in Python.

I know how to upload one volatile table, but I can't figure out how to create more than that (in order to `join` them together in the end).

Here is a simple example:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(method="odbc", dsn="TD_DWH_PROD")
curs = cnxn.cursor()

curs.execute

("""

CREATE  VOLATILE TABLE Atable , NO LOG AS  (

SELECT Cust_ID,
       Purchase_Date

FROM   S1

) WITH  DATA PRIMARY INDEX(Cust_ID) ON  COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

END TRANSACTION;

""")
```

Now, let's say I want to add another table:

```
curs.execute

("""
CREATE  VOLATILE TABLE Btable , NO LOG AS  (
SELECT Cust_ID,
       Cust_Entry_Date
FROM   S2
) WITH  DATA PRIMARY INDEX(Cust_ID) ON  COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
END TRANSACTION;
""")
```

And `join` them together at the end of the process:

```
curs.execute

("""

Select S1.Cust_ID,
       Purchase_Date,
       Cust_Entry_Date
FROM   S1

Join   S2
  On   S1.Cust_ID=S2.Cust_ID; 

END TRANSACTION;
""")
```

Is there a way of doing it in Python?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does it happen if you indeed do what you are describing here? It doesn't work? Is it giving an error?

Comment: I tried to run 2 volatile tables (without even `joining` them) and I'm getting the following error: _pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('25000', '[25000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Too many END TRANSACTION statements.  (-3510) (SQLExecDirectW)_

Comment: Try remove the "END TRANSACTION" from the first statement.

Comment: My hypothesis is that pyodbc is forcing an initial BEGIN TRANSACTION when connecting, so the first END TRANSACTION works while the second is unbalanced and so it returns an error. By the way, is your ODBC connection configured as ANSI Transaction mode (TMODE=ANSI) or Teradata Transaction mode (TMODE=TERA)?

Comment: I removed the first `END TRANSACTION` and the error massage changed to: _pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('25000', '[25000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.  (-3932) (SQLExecDirectW)')_


Regarding your question, I'm not so sure if it is ANSI or Tera.. can you tell me how can I check it.

Comment: The TMODE property should be defined in your ODBC datasource (if you don't see it, we are using TERA mode). I've found this link (https://developer.teradata.com/blog/odbcteam/2016/02/python-with-teradata-odbc) where it says that DDL statements should be committed. In your case it would mean to write "cnxn.commit()" after the volatile creations (disclaimer: I used Teradata via Java and jdbc, so I don't have the answer for python but I'm trying to help)

Comment: I tried to use `cnxn.commit()`, but it doesn't help (when I'm using `cnxn.commit()` with single volatile table, it works perfect). I'd like to thank you anyway for your time..!!